# padding zeros at the beginning of a printf statement C

Tags: c, printf, zero-padding

I need to add 0's to some values.

For example if the number is 14, i want to print out 00014.

but I can't just use %05d because the number of padding I want is stored in a variable.

If the variable is equal to 6, I want to print 000014. If it is equal to 3, I want to print out 014 and so on..

Any quick way to do it?

```
int length = 5;
int someValue = 14;
printf("%0%d%d",length,someValue);
```

This also doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: `printf ("%0*d\n", width, 14);` where `width` is the *field-width* you want to use (e.g. `5` or `6`, etc..)

Comment: Alternatively, there is,nothing to stop you assembling your entire format string 'dynamically' at run time, e.g. with a sprintf() with your variable as an argument.  There is nothing that limits format strings to compile-time const strings:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an asterisk `*` in the format to tell `printf` to get the field width from an argument:

```
printf("%0*d", length, someValue);
```

You can also use it for precision.

See e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 printf("%0*d",length,someValue);
```

where the field-width is marked using the `*` and the corresponding value is taken from the first argument.